# Fragment not attached to a context issues

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment

when I use the requireContext() method in the fragment, sometimes long operations occur. This error occurs when the user suddenly closes the application or moves to another page. What solution should I do? I don't want to check with isAdded wherever there is requireContext. There must be a solution for this.

Example Code Block:

```
dailyBinding.headertext.animateText(SharedPreferencesReceiver.getName(requireContext()));
if (SharedPreferencesReceiver.getTopProVisibility(requireContext())) {
    UIHandler.post(() -> {
        if (SharedPreferencesReceiver.getNoticeActivity(requireContext())) {
            dailyBinding.adss.setText("TEST");
        } else {
            dailyBinding.adss.setText("TEST 22");
        }
        dailyBinding.mainprocv.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            dailyBinding.adss.setText("TEST");
            startActivity(new Intent(requireActivity(), NoticeActivity.class));
        });
        dailyBinding.mainprocv.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            dailyBinding.mainprocv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SharedPreferencesReceiver.setTopProVisibility(requireContext(), false);
            SharedPreferencesReceiver.setProRemoveText(requireContext(), false);
            return true;
        });
    });
} else {
    dailyBinding.mainprocv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: If your operation lives beyond when the Fragment reaches `onDestroy`, you already have a memory leak. Where are you cancelling your work?